# Add style to div which is loading after document.ready in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, calendar

I am using calendar.js in django for which I am unable to add style "z-index:1000" (so that it will show the calender correctly) to the div with class name as calendarbox which is loading after the page load.

I tried following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".calendarbox").css("z-index", 1000);
    });
</script>
```

The Calendarbox Div is loading after the page load.

CSS:

```
<div id="calendarbox0" class="calendarbox module" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 2079px; top: 1340px;">
<div>
<div id="calendarin0" class="calendar">
--------
```

Comment: do you have link to the plugin documentation?

Comment: It looks like a hack but not a solution. Why don't you describe this rule in CSS?

Comment: I am using the django customer daterange filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this rule to the css file:

CSS

```
.calendarbox { z-index:1000 }
```

Check the following example.

```js
$('#add').on('click', function() {
  $('body').append('<span class="newElem">New element!</span>');
});
```

```css
.newElem { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add new element</button>
```

**NOTE**

It is better to collect all the styling into a css file instead of giving it inline, so make some changes here (unless if this styling needs to be calculated by js):

HTML

```
<div id="calendarbox0" class="calendarbox module">
<div id="calendarin0" class="calendar"> ...
```

CSS

```
.calendarbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2079px;
  top: 1340px;
}

.calendar { z-index:1000 }
```

Comment: As soon as the new element has class 'calendarbox' which is defined inside the css that your page loads, this element will follow this rule, unless it gets overwritten by another rule!

Comment: Does the rule apply even for the div which has display:none; before clicking on calendar it is display:none; as soon as the user clicks on calendar it is display:block; and the above style is not applying for the div with class name or ID.

Comment: Of course! But it will be invisible because of display:none :)

Comment: Can you please let me know what are all the possible reasons why the css not apply to my div?

Comment: It might be overwritten by another css rule, I can't be absolutely sure.. Check out the console for the applied css